# How to make Dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, select

I try to make dynamic dependent dropdown. When user selects region, he has to choose from another dropdown of schools, which are in this region. I know there are many tutorials, I tried some ways, but I'm new to jQuery and I cant make it. Here's my view:

```html
<html>
<head>
 
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       $(function() {
$('#region').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url()?>index.php/home/get_schools",
                data: "region="+$('#region').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                        $('#school').empty();
                        var unassigned = $('#school').attr('options');
                        unassigned[0] = new Option('UNASSIGNED', 0, true, true);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                            var options = $('#school').attr('options');
                            options[options.length] = new Option(data[i].school_name, true, true);
 
                        }
                 }
          });
  });
 });


    </script>  
  <?php
   echo "<body>";
  
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open('home/register');
 echo "<table border = '0' >";
echo "<tr><td>  Region:*  </td><td>";
echo "<select name = 'region[]' id='region' >";
  foreach($regions as $row) 
  {
    echo '<option value= "'.$row->region.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
  } 
  echo "</select>";
  
  
   echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>  School:*  </td><td>";
echo '<select id="school">';
  echo '<option>Please choose region</option>';
  echo '</select>';
  
  echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
 echo form_submit($data);
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
```

My controller is:

```html
 public function get_schools(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');    
       $region = $this->input->post('region');
    $schools = $this->user_form->get_schools_by_region($school);
    echo json_encode($schools);
             
    }
```

My model is:

```html
   function get_schools_by_region ($region){
        if($region){
        $this->db->select('school_id, school_name');
         $this->db->where("region = " . $region);
        $query = $this->db->get('schools');
       

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
                return $query->result();
        
        }else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }  
}
```

Would you help me? :)

Comment: You had same topic already? However, can you edit code and show in example how it should look like (html). Also, you have loaded jQuery twice with no reason. Better would be to check if not loaded to load it again.

Comment: What is your code producing and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems here. I would use the least amount of PHP possible in my view. I would also remake the .ajax call to .post since it is easier to read, and turn that json result into an object for easier iteration. Check out the modifications I made and try it out. Let me know if it all works:

HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <?= validation_errors(); ?>
            <form action="home/register">
                <table border='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Region:*</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='region' id='region'>
                                <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
                                    <option value= "<?= $row->region ?>"><?= $row->region ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select> 
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>School:*</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="school">
                                <option>Please choose region</option>
                            </select> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#region').change(function() {
                var url = <?= base_url() ?> + "index.php/home/get_schools";
                var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                    var $school_sel = $('#school');
                    $school_sel.empty();
                    $school_sel.append("<option>Please choose region</option>");
                    var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                        var option = "<option>" + val.school_name + "</option>";
                        $school_sel.append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

PHP Controller:

```
function get_schools() {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $region = $this->input->post('region');
    $schools = $this->user_form->get_schools_by_region($region);
    echo json_encode($schools);
}
```

PHP Model:

```
function get_schools_by_region($region = null) {
    if ($region) {
        $this->db->select('school_id, school_name');
        $this->db->where("region", $region);
        $query = $this->db->get('schools');


        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it doesn't work. I used this code.

Comment: I don't know. Now I look at the code to seek errors. In the second dropdown it's "Please choose region" - does not show any schools.

Comment: weird.. I have some time right now. Would you like me to help you remotely, maybe through Teamviewer?

Comment: Would you like to send to you my files in mail? :)

Comment: Let me know when you send the files

Comment: I sent you the files in mail.